# Error Code: 1172. Results consisted in more than one row error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have 2 tables named Employee(employeeID, salary) and Tax(employeeID, tax, revisedSalary), my aim is to calculate the tax and revised salary for all of the employees by extracting the values of the Salary column in the Employee Table, perform the calculations and store the results in the Tax table all this using stored procedures

Here is what I've tried to accomplish that, but without success so far, I'm getting 'Results consisted in more than one row' error:

```
delimiter //
create procedure calcTax()
begin
  declare tax, salary, revisedSalary double default 0.0;
  declare i int;
  select Salary from Employee into salary;
  while i <= salary do
  if salary >= 0.0 and salary<= 10000.0
  then
    set tax = salary * 10/100;
     set revisedSalary = salary - tax;
  end if;
    insert into Tax (tax, revisedSalary) values(tax, revisedSalary);
    set i = i + 1;
end while;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: You cannot store a resultset in a scalar variable. ie select Salary from Employee into salary;is not possible

Comment: Any reason why you think you have to use a stored procedure?

Comment: @P.Salmon I am learning mySQL, so I was given such a task whereby I have to use stored procedures to perform such operation.

Comment: If the task only says use an sp then you could drop my answer into an sp and it would work - but without seeing the wording I cannot say if my code in an sp would fulfil the requirement even though it does fulfil the question posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you cannot store a result set in a variable your question doesn't make a lot of sense since you are attempting to calculate tax and salary per employee and you are inserting rows to tax without reference to employee. Also a while loop is unnecessary, the same can be achieved with a simple insert select

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,tax;
CREATE TABLE T
(employeeid int, salary int);
create table tax
(employeeid int, tax int , revisedsalary int);

insert into t values
(1,0),(2,5000),(3,7000),(4,15000);

insert into tax 
select employeeid,
         salary * .10,
         salary - (salary * .10)
from t
where salary > 0 and salary <= 10000;

select * from tax;

+------------+------+---------------+
| employeeid | tax  | revisedsalary |
+------------+------+---------------+
|          2 |  500 |          5000 |
|          3 |  700 |          7000 |
+------------+------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

If you must us an sp

```
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
 insert into tax 
    select employeeid,
             salary * .10,
             salary - (salary * .10)
    from t
    where salary > 0 and salary <= 10000;
    
    select * from tax;
end $$
delimiter ;

call p();
```